# How to ping servers on page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to ping 12 server ips when page is opening. I tried  this(for 1 ip):

```
public int sisup;
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Ping p = new Ping();
    PingReply r;

    String s = "10.1.1.1";

    r = p.Send(s); 
    Response.Buffer = false;
    if (r.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        sisup = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        sisup = 0;
    }
}
```

And doing something with sisup. It's working, but so slowely. Page loading takes a few secs because of ping. How can I do this without page loading? Can I do this after page load? Or any suggestion for ping? I need just servers are up or down, and do something.

Or maybe I can set ping response time. It's local network, response time just 1-2 ms. I think ping waiting reply so long.

Comment: You may want to look into using ajax calls for this. This would allow the page itself to load quickly without data and then you can send one (or twelve) ajax requests to the server to ask for the ping information.

Comment: Can you load the page, then initiate the ping with an Ajax call? - http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using `Parallel.For`.

```
Parallel.For(0, 12, i =>
{
    // ping each server
});
```

This way all pings will run in parallel and your response time will be like 10 times or so lower.

Alternatively you can ping after page load using jQuery to make AJAX calls.

```
$.ajax("PingServer.url")
.done(function() {
    alert("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("error");
});
```

It's a little more work but this will work best.

Comment: Thanks but still so slow. I think must ping after loading page.

Comment: Your edit states to do a jquery post to a PHP-file. The OP is using C# - ASP.NET so I wouldn't think that this is an option.

Comment: Only stating that to have PHP in your example isn't really showing the OP the option he is looking for.